# Read excel object in excel file using aspose error

Tags: c#, excel, aspose-cells

I'm using **Aspose Cells for .NET** in my **ASP.NET MVC** project.

First I read the Excel objects in Excel files and than using `File.WriteAllBytes` to save the Excel object , but it can't be read.

I opened the saved Excel files, but MS Excel just shows a gray background, nothing else shows.

Other format files like .doc can be saved and opened.

I'm stuck by this problem for 1 day , may anyone help me solve this? Big thanks!

Comment: This might be a bug of Aspose.Cells, you should try the latest version of Aspose.Cells and check if it makes any difference. ---- Shakeel Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Finally figured this out , the default setting of Aspose creating an excel file is workbook.Worksheets.IsHidden = true, so change it to false will solve this problem. Thanks anyway!